# Values in array read in from d3.csv are undefined outside of function despite global variable declaration

Tags: javascript, csv, google-maps, d3.js, async-await

Thank you in advance for your help!
I have declared four arrays globally in my code. Then, in the function to read the data from the csv, I assign the data values to array elements. However, the array elements are undefined outside of this function, and I can't seem to find the issue...
I am using d3 version 7 () and Google Maps Javascript API.

My CSV file is formatted Project_Name, Artist, Lat, Long - with around 300 values.

```
// Request needed libraries.
const { Map, InfoWindow } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
const { LatLng } = await google.maps.importLibrary("core");
const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

//Global Vars
let map;
let projectName = [];
let artist = [];
let lat = [];
let long = [];
let markers = [];


async function data() {
  d3.csv("/data/single.csv", function(d) {
    return {
      projectName: +d.Project_Name,
      artist: +d.Artist,
      lat: +d.Latitude,
      long: +d.Longitude,
    }
  }).then(function(d) {
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
      projectName[i] = d[i].Project_Name;
      artist[i] = d[i].Artist;
      lat[i] = parseFloat(d[i].Latitude);
      long[i] = parseFloat(d[i].Longitude);
    }
  });
}



function createMarkers(m){
  for (var z=0; z < lat.length; z++) {
    markers[z] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat[z], long[z]),
      map: m,
      title: projectName[z],
    });
  } 
}

async function initMap() {
  
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: { lat: 37.4239163, lng: -122.0947209 },
    mapId: "[MAP ID]",
    mapTypeControl: false,
  });
  const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "",
    disableAutoPan: true,
  });
  
  //READ CSV FILE
  data();
  
  //MARKERS
  createMarkers(map);
  
}

initMap();
```

I tried using await, that didn't solve the problem. Also tried to use setTimeout, which resulted in the value of NaN instead of undefined.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think you still need to parse the csv file into object and read as text. have you tried that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that `d3.csv` is asynchronous. You got the right idea by wanting to await somewhere, but you have to await the `d3.csv` promise.
If you want to "await" data to be filled, you have to return `d3.csv` promise :

```
async function data() {
  return d3.csv("/data/single.csv", function(d) {
   ...
  });
}
```

Then await the data function before calling `createMarkers();` :

```
... 
    //READ CSV FILE
    await data();
    // now your global arrays should be filled
    createMarkers();
...
```